# Force nested divs to have min-height of 100%?

Tags: css, layout, position, height

I know that `min-height: 100%` will only work to take up a minimum of 100% of its parent element's height if the parent element has some numeric value for height, but what if I have a few nested divs and I want them all to have a min-height of 100%? I tried `min-height:inherit` but that didn't work either? I know I can probably solve this problem with JavaScript by simply checking the browser height value on document load and then assigning that to the min-height property of my nested divs, but I'd like to know if it would be possible to solve this with just css?

**Edit**: I should also mention that I need my outer most div and my nested divs all to have a min-height of 100% such that they take up at least the height of the browser, but expand if needed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`min-height: inherit;` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/ugxbs/

**EDIT**

As for percentage values and the expected behavior, there is no logic behind *nested* min-height. What you should do is to use the `height` property for all parents, then add min-height to the inner most `DIV`.

F.ex:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .outer { height: 100% }
.inner { min-height: 100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4PsdT/

This way, you are telling the browser to set all outer elements from the top (`HTML`) to a height of 100%. This will make these elements stretch across the browser height. Then just add a `min-height` to the inner most element that contains the content.

Setting a `height` doesn’t mean that it’s children’s excessive content will fall out, unless you add `overflow:hidden;`. 
​

Comment: I know it would work when the outer most div has a numeric value for min-height, but it will fail when the outer most div has a percentage for min-height (which is what I need in my case). I need all my nested div's to take up the height of the browser window at least, so my outer most div should have a min-height of 100% unless there's another way to go about this problem.

Comment: @hesson See my edit for an attempt to explain why nested min-height is not a logical approach to the problem.

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I needed!

Comment: Actually, setting the outer's height to 100% does make it's children's excessive content to fail out. At least, if there is an outer's sibling after it, it will be covered by the inner's content. http://jsfiddle.net/uL34X/1/

Answer (score 0):

I can make it work with the property height but not min-height.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDVqm/