# Nesting multiple elements with min-height:100%;

Tags: css, nested

I have multiple elements with a `min-height` of `100%`. These are the child of my html which has a `height` of `100%`.
Only the first child of the html recieves the `min-height:100%;` it gets ignored for the remaining childs.

This question has been asked before and so far the only answer I found states: "Give all elements but the last child a `height` of `100%` and give the last child a `min-height` of `100%`".

This sollution does not work however when the elements become larger than the actual page.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h2turnte/3/) 
I want to make this example so, that the red border on the side of element `#left` stretches at least to the bottom of the screen, but when the page becomes larger I want it to stretch to the end of the page.

As you can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/h2turnte/2/), the `height:100%;` fix becomes a problem when the content is stretched longer than the actual screen.

So how would I create a fix that lets the red border always stretch the complete page. Whether the page is filled or not?

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916531/force-nested-divs-to-have-min-height-of-100) (See also the comment of Alex Che to this accepted answer, that describes my problem exactly)

Comment: please, don't use floats for this (it's what's causing this behaviour). Use positioning instead.

Comment: @jbutler483 `positioning`? You mean `display:inline-block`?

Comment: No, I meant positioning of your elements. Try fiddling with position:relative, and position: absolute and see what you can come up with. I'll see if ~I can dig up a simple column example for you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27634761/3436942) which might help you in terms of laying out your design

Comment: [Or see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uL34X/2/) - for a 'fixed' version of Alex Che's comment